# Guidance for making a program with only pure assembly on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, assembly

I have realized I have to study Assembly language to understand programming deeply during trying to implement coroutine.

So I decided to start study Assembly. I want to start this by making small programs with only pure assembly. What's required and where should I start from? Easy Tutorials? Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks.

PS.
I'm using Mac OS X 10.6 on iMac Core i5 machine.

Answer (score 1):

MIPS is a nice and short instruction set.

Nothing fancy to get in your way.

**MIPS Emulators**

- SPIM was a classic emulator used for years. Some useful info [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPIM).
- [Mars](http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/) looks promising and runs in java.

Comment: I'll take a look. Thanks for suggestion. I like the words 'nothing fancy' :)